# cTypes C program for create_string_buffer used in python

Tags: python, c, string, buffer, ctypes

I am learning ctypes. But there is no clear explanation for create_string_buffer anywhere.
What is the equivalent c program for this ?

when do we use create_string_buffer in c program ?

```
from ctypes import *
p = create_string_buffer(3)            # create a 3 byte buffer, initialized to NUL bytes
print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))

p = create_string_buffer(b"Hello")     # create a buffer containing a NUL terminated string
print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))

print(repr(p.value))

p = create_string_buffer(b"Hello", 10) # create a 10 byte buffer
print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))

p.value = b"Hi"
print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))
```

Can you explain create_string_buffer with any other simple c program and its equivalent python program representation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`create_string_buffer` to create mutable memory blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer) and pass into C function which expects a *pointer to a buffer that receives data* . Most of the platform APIs work like this. Also *Cpython* [source code contains few usages of `create_string_buffer`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/736684b1bb67369a2e95a9f621752deead44e7ef/Lib/test/test_os.py#L2417).

For example, consider [`PeekNamedPipe` windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-peeknamedpipe). It has the following signature.

```
BOOL PeekNamedPipe(
  [in]            HANDLE  hNamedPipe,
  [out, optional] LPVOID  lpBuffer,
  [in]            DWORD   nBufferSize,
  [out, optional] LPDWORD lpBytesRead,
  [out, optional] LPDWORD lpTotalBytesAvail,
  [out, optional] LPDWORD lpBytesLeftThisMessage
);
```

The second parameter to this API must be a [mutable buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-peeknamedpipe#parameters).

> `[out, optional] lpBuffer`
>
> **A pointer to a buffer that receives data** read from the pipe. This
> parameter can be NULL if no data is to be read.

To consume this API from python level, you can relay on `create_string_buffer` to  [construct the mutable buffer filled with NULL bytes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/736684b1bb67369a2e95a9f621752deead44e7ef/Lib/test/test_os.py#L2420) and pass it as second argument to the `PeekNamedPipe` call.

```
buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(len(msg))
rslt = PeekNamedPipe(msvcrt.get_osfhandle(proc.stdout.fileno()),
                     buf, ctypes.sizeof(buf), None, None, None)
```

So once the `PeekNamedPipe` call succeeded, buffer(`buf`) will be populated [with the result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/namedpipeapi/nf-namedpipeapi-peeknamedpipe#return-value).